# How to use jinja templates for xml?

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

I am trying to use the jinja template as we use it in HTML.

```py
# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from CallCenter.views import view_assets

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name="index"),
    path('assets', view_assets)
]
```

```py
# views.py
def view_assets(request):
    return render(request, "CallCenter/new.xml")
```

```
<!--base.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
     <Say>
          {% block content %}
          {% endblock %}
     </Say>
</Response>
```

```
<!--new.xml-->
{% block content %}
Say this!
{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, it gets wrapped in HTML tags, and I don't want that. The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html class="gr_4a9e18fa_ngrok_io">
<head></head>
<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
   <response>
     <say>
          Say this!
     </say>
   </response>
</body>
</html>
```

The expected output should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
     <Say>
          Say this!
     </Say>
</Response>
```

I am using ngrok to access the /assets page. And the output that I had I got is through ngrok_address/assets/new.xml

Comment: Django is not wrapping anything.

Comment: @DanielRoseman jinja is adding the html, head and the response is in body tags. I want the xml file to be like [link](https://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml). Is it possible to get the same output using jinja?

Comment: It really isn't. Jinja won't add anything you haven't asked for. Where are you getting this output? And how are you rendering the register?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I wanted to access these xml files I would be creating so I added a path to my urls and I was accessing the files through that. I've edited the question to include my urls.py and the views.py function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something in the added html markup could be a clue ?

```
<html class="gr_4a9e18fa_ngrok_io">
```

Can you spot something here ? No ? Ok, another hint:

> I am using ngrok to access the /assets page

You may want to fix your code to pass the correct content-type ("text/xml" or "application/xml") to `render()` - which you SHOULD do anyway. Now I don't know much about ngrok so I can't tell if this will fix the issue - there might be other reasons why you see this added markup -, but in all cases your issue is with ngrok, not with Django nor Jinja2.

Comment: adding content_type='application/xml' to the function in view.py fixed the issue. Thank you.